# How do I change the default download folder in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Every time I download something in Chrome it goes to a folder that is not convenient to me so how can change it to a folder of my choosing?

Comment: Do you want a different default folder or a custom folder for each download?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check under the `Wrench icon / Settings / Show advanced settings / Downloads` section, where you can either set a default download location, or have the browser prompt you for a location every single time. More details [here](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95574).