# How to control where saved images go rather than automatically to "downloads" in Google Chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the default download folder in Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/477264/how-do-i-change-the-default-download-folder-in-chrome)

I am being forced to change to Google Chrome because I have Windows XP and Explorer 8 will not be supported much longer. I am slowly adapting to Chrome except for one very annoying thing. When I try to save an image from an email (embedded or attached), there seems to be an automatic default to the "downloads" folder. I then have to go there and redirect it to the folder I want it to be in on my hard drive.

With Windows 7, when I elected to save, I could immediately specify the folder where it should be saved. With Chrome, I have this extra step of things going into "downloads" and then I have to redirect them. While it just seems like a minor additional step, multiply that by a couple of hundreds of emails each day and it gets really annoying and time consuming.

Is there some way to disconnect the automatic save to "downloads" and let me immediately specify where else it should go? Any help with this would be much appreciated

Answer (score 4):

You can open Google Chrome Settings and click on "Show advanced settings..." at the bottom, to show the setting where you can change the default downloads location from

> C:\Users\UserName\Downloads

to any custom location you want.

[image: Download Setting]

Additionally, you can opt for "Ask where to save each file before downloading" if you do not want a default download location and instead want to choose where to save, each time  you download a file.